# ghost.org official container has no volumes defined for persisting the data

Tags: containers, ghost-blog

When I use the docker compose file (https://hub.docker.com/_/ghost) I do not see any volumes.  Where is the data persisted or how is that achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I investigated this and here's the answer: both the mysql:8.0 and the ghost:4-alpine containers will create unnamed volumes to store the persistent data.  If you want to override them and created named one, you can do that.  I did it and it works like a charm using something like:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  ghost:
    volumes:
        - ghost_data:/var/lib/ghost/content
    image: ghost:4-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:2368
    environment:
      # see https://ghost.org/docs/config/#configuration-options
      database__client: mysql
      database__connection__host: db
      database__connection__user: root
      database__connection__password: example
      database__connection__database: ghost
      # this url value is just an example, and is likely wrong for your environment!
      url: http://localhost:8080
      # contrary to the default mentioned in the linked documentation, this image defaults to NODE_ENV=production (so development mode needs to be explicitly specified if desired)
      #NODE_ENV: development

  db:
    volumes:
        - ghost_db:/var/lib/mysql
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

volumes:
    ghost_db:
    ghost_data:
```

Bye defining the volumes globally they can be accessed from any containers if need be.